# Select names of columns which contain specific values in row

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using a data.frame:

```
        data.frame("A"=c(NA,5,NA,NA,NA),
                   "B"=c(1,2,3,4,NA),
                   "C"=c(NA,NA,NA,2,3),
                   "D"=c(NA,NA,NA,7,NA))
```

This delivers a data.frame in this form:

```
   A  B  C  D
1 NA  1 NA NA
2  5  2 NA NA
3 NA  3 NA NA
4 NA  4  2  7
5 NA NA  3 NA
```

My aim is to check **each row** of the data.frame, if there is a **value greater than a specific one** (let's assume 2) and to get the name of the columns where this is the case.

The desired output (value greater 2) should be:

```
for row 1 of the data.frame
x[1,]: c()

for row 2
x[2,]: c("A")

for row3
x[3,]: c("B")

for row4
x[4,]: c("B","D")

and for row5 of the data.frame
x[5,]: c("C")
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `which`:

```
lapply(apply(dat, 1, function(x)which(x>2)), names)
```

with `dat` being your data frame.

```
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
[1] "A"

[[3]]
[1] "B"

[[4]]
[1] "B" "D"

[[5]]
[1] "C"
```

**EDIT**
Shorter version suggested by flodel:

```
lapply(apply(dat > 2, 1, which), names)
```

---

**Edit: (from Arun)**

First, there's no need for `lapply` and `apply`. You can get the same just with `apply`:

```
apply(dat > 2, 1, function(x) names(which(x)))
```

But, using `apply` on a `data.frame` will coerce it into a matrix, which may not be wise if the data.frame is huge.

Comment: why do you need a `lapply` there? `apply(df>2, 1, function(x) names(which(x)))` will do it, isn't it?

Comment: @Arun, `lapply` guarantees that you get a list as the output, no matter what. With `apply`, the output class will depend on the input, which is a very bad thing (try with `dat[2:3,]` for example). Also note how the `lapply` version is overall shorter and does not require an anonymous function, so I also find it nicer, but that's suggestive I agree.

Comment: ... but as it seems, all answers are still wrong. This will work with all inputs: `lapply(split(dat, rownames(dat)), function(x)names(x)[which(x > 2)])`

Comment: @flodel, my answer wont fit in the comments section, so I've posted an answer :). Let me know if you disagree/have other suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

To answer @flodel's concerns, I'll write it as a separate answer:

#### 1) Using `lapply` gets a list and `apply` doesn't guarantee this always:

A fair point. I'll illustrate the issue with an example:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(3, 5, NA, NA, NA), B = c(1, 2, 3, 1, NA), 
    C = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 3), D = c(NA, NA, NA, 7, NA)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

   A  B  C  D
1  3  1 NA NA
2  5  2 NA NA
3 NA  3 NA NA
4 NA  1  2  7
5 NA NA  3 NA

# using `apply` results in a vector:
apply(df, 1, function(x) names(which(x>2)))
# [1] "A" "A" "B" "D" "C"
```

**So, how can we *guarantee* a list with `apply`?**

By creating a `list` within the function argument and then use `unlist` with `recursive = FALSE`, as shown below:

```
unlist(apply(df, 1, function(x) list(names(which(x>2)))), recursive=FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] "A"

[[2]]
[1] "A"

[[3]]
[1] "B"

[[4]]
[1] "D"

[[5]]
[1] "C"
```

#### 2) `lapply` is overall shorter, and does not require anonymous function:

Yes, but it's slower. Let me illustrate this on a big example.

```
set.seed(45)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:10, NA), 1e5 * 100, replace=TRUE), 
               ncol = 100))

system.time(t1 <- lapply(apply(df > 2, 1, which), names))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.025   0.342   5.651 

system.time(t2 <- unlist(apply(df, 1, function(x) 
            list(names(which(x>2)))), recursive=FALSE))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.860   0.181   3.065 

identical(t1, t2) # TRUE
```

#### 3) All answers are wrong and the answer that'll work with all inputs:

```
lapply(split(df, rownames(df)), function(x)names(x)[which(x > 2)])
```

First, I don't get as to what's wrong. If you're talking about the list being `unnamed`, this can be changed by just setting the names *just once* at the end.

Second, unfortunately, using `split` on a **huge data.frame** which will result in too many split elements will be *terribly slow* (due to huge factor levels).

```
# testing on huge data.frame
system.time(t3 <- lapply(split(df, rownames(df)), function(x)names(x)[which(x > 2)]))
   user  system elapsed
517.545   0.312 517.872
```

Third, this orders the elements as `1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, ...` instead of `1 .. 1e5`. Instead one could just use `setNames` or `setnames` (from `data.table` package) to just do this once finally, as shown below:

```
# setting names just once
t2 <- setNames(t2, rownames(df)) # by copy

# or even better using `data.table` `setattr` function to 
# set names by reference
require(data.table)
tracemem(t2)
setattr(t2, 'names', rownames(df))
tracemem(t2)
```

Comparing the output doesn't show any other difference between the two (`t3` and `t2`). You could run this to verify that the outputs are same (time consuming):

```
all(sapply(names(t2), function(x) all(t2[[x]] == t3[[x]])) == TRUE) # TRUE
```

Comment: *First, I don't get as to what's wrong*: at the time, all proposed answers where either not systematically returning a list (e.g. with `df[2:3,]`), or not returning the correct result (e.g. with `df[2:3,]` as well.). Your `unlist(apply(...` solution fixes that problem, good job.

Answer (score 1):

why not do

```
colnames(df[,df[i,]>2])
```

for each row, where df is your data frame and i is the row number ;)