# Select/Get names of all columns which have a negative value between 0-10

Tags: r, range, lapply, negative-number

For a dataframe, I would like to get the names of, or select, all the columns which have negative values within a certain range. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261814/select-names-of-columns-which-contain-specific-values-in-row) post comes pretty close, but it iterates trough the rows which is not feasible for my data. In addition, if I store that solution it becomes a list, where I would prefer a vector. As an example, for the following dataset:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
     "A   B   D   E  iso   year   
      0   1   1   NA ECU   2009   
      1   0   2   0  ECU   2009   
      0   0   -3  0  BRA   2011   
      1   0   4   0  BRA   2011   
      0   1   7   NA ECU   2008   
     -1   0   1   0  ECU   2008   
      0   0   3   2  BRA   2012   
      1   0   4   NA BRA   2012",
  header = TRUE
)
```

I would want to have the names of all columns which have negative values between 0 and 10 (A and D in the example). What would be the easiest solution to achieve this? Everything else equal a data.table solution would be preferred.

Comment: So you want to identify columns that have all values bigger than -10 and smaller than 0?

Comment: Hey tmfmnk. Almost.. I want the identity of columns which have ANY values bigger than -10 and smaller than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
 df %>%
 gather(var, val, -c(5:6)) %>%
 group_by(var) %>%
 summarise(res = any(val[!is.na(val)] > -10 & val[!is.na(val)] < 0))

  var   res  
  <chr> <lgl>
1 A     TRUE 
2 B     FALSE
3 D     TRUE 
4 E     FALSE
```

To select only numeric columns:

```
df %>%
 select_if(is.numeric) %>%
 gather(var, val) %>%
 group_by(var) %>%
 summarise(res = any(val[!is.na(val)] > -10 & val[!is.na(val)] < 0))
```

Note that it also selects "year" column as it is a numeric column.

You can do this also with `base R`:

```
df <- Filter(is.numeric, df)
cond <- as.logical(colSums(df > -10, na.rm = TRUE) *
                    colSums(df < -0, na.rm = TRUE))
colnames(df[, cond])

[1] "A" "D"
```

Or written as a "one-liner":

```
df <- Filter(is.numeric, df)
colnames(df[, as.logical(colSums(df > -10, na.rm = TRUE) * colSums(df < -0, na.rm = TRUE))])
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
 "A   B   D   E  iso   year   
      0   1   1   NA ECU   2009   
      1   0   2   0  ECU   2009   
      0   0   -3  0  BRA   2011   
      1   0   4   0  BRA   2011   
      0   1   7   NA ECU   2008   
     -1   0   1   0  ECU   2008   
      0   0   3   2  BRA   2012   
      1   0   4   NA BRA   2012", 
 header = TRUE,
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer tmfmnk! Would it be possible to deselect the non-numerical columns with something like `!is.numeric` instead of `-c(5:6)` ? This would work on the example, but would give problems for the large datasets I have..

Comment: It appears to also work by replacing `-c(5:6)` with `cols`, where cols is : `cols=sapply(df, is.numeric)` - `cols=names(cols)[cols]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another `tidyverse` variant:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(iso,year) %>% 
   keep(~any(.x>-10 & .x<0 & !is.na(.x))) %>% 
   names()
 "A" "D"
```

**EDIT**:
To handle factors, use `mutate_if`.
We could similarly do(although I would think grouping would be better):

```
  df %>% 
   mutate_if(is.factor,as.character) %>% 
   purrr::keep(~any(.x>-10 & .x<0 & !is.na(.x))) %>% 
   names()
[1] "A" "D"
```

Values:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(iso,year) %>% 
   keep(~any(.x>-10 & .x<0 & !is.na(.x)))
# A tibble: 8 x 2
      A     D
  <int> <int>
1     0     1
2     1     2
3     0    -3
4     1     4
5     0     7
6    -1     1
7     0     3
8     1     4
```

Comment: Thanks NelsonGon! Would there be any way to get this to work without specifying before which columns are non-numerical?  As explained, this works very nicely on the example, but would give problems for the large datasets I have..

Comment: Not sure. Here we are not testing for `non_numeric`s as `keep` handles that. It will(I think) discard any non_numeric data hence eliminating the need to check beforehand. Could you share what happens on your data set?

Comment: I get the following error for your first solution: `Error: Predicate functions must return a single TRUE or FALSE, not a missing value
Call rlang::last_error() to see a backtrace
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(.x, -10) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(.x, 0) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: Verified! Thank you so much!